# Cucumber "--format progress" doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, format, cucumber

In my cucumber.yml I've tried to add this option (`default: --drb --format progress`), but it return an error :

```
Exception encountered: #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
Error creating formatter: progress>
```

When I take it in brackets `default: --drb --"format progress"` it doesn't helps:

```
invalid option: --format progress (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
```

So maybe there is no option, but [it should be](http://cukes.info/cucumber/api/ruby/latest/Cucumber/Formatter/Progress.html)

And "format pretty" works correctly without any brackets.
I want see not all scenarios in console, but just which has an errors, perhaps there is another way to do this.

Full trace:

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
Error creating formatter: progress (ArgumentError)
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:1543:in `initialize'

/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:168:in `new'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:168:in `block in formatters'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:163:in `map'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:163:in `formatters'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:68:in `build_tree_walker'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
```

And If I write option in cucumer.yml the error slightly different:

```
Exception encountered: #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
Error creating formatter: progress>
backtrace:
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:1543:in `initialize'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:168:in `new'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:168:in `block in formatters'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:163:in `map'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:163:in `formatters'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:68:in `build_tree_walker'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework/cucumber.rb:24:in `run_tests'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in `block in run'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/server.rb:48:in `run'
/home/alder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1558:in `perform_without_block'
/home/alder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1518:in `perform'
/home/alder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1592:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
/home/alder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1588:in `loop'
/home/alder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1588:in `block in main_loop'
```

I have a Spork by the way maybe it's a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the updated information in your question, I think I see the problem (hence I'm posting another answer as it's completely different to my other one).  It looks like Cucumber is trying to instantiate an ActiveRecord class, so I suspect you have a model named 'Progress' in your project somewhere, which Cucumber is trying to create instead of of the actual formatter.

I was able to reproduce your problem (close enough, anyway) by adding this class in the 'support' folder:

```
class Progress
    def initialize
        raise "I don't exist!"
    end
end
```

According to the docs, you should be able to specify a fully qualified class name here i.e. `--format Cucumber::Formatter::Progress`, to force Cucumber to use it's own formatter.  However, I tried this and it still doesn't work, there seems to be a bug in how Cucumber resolves the fully-qualified name.

I was able to get around this by adding this line to my `env.rb` file:

```
require 'cucumber/formatter/progress'
```

Which then allowed me to run `cucumber --format progress` successfully.

I think that, as `env.rb` gets executed before any other code, then Cucumber's `Progress` class will be the first one that gets found when creating the formatter.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for such detailed response, I just add `require` in `env` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the output you've pasted in, that you have an extra angle ('>') bracket floating around in your `cucumber.yml` file:

> Error creating formatter: progress>

Unless that's a typo in your question, for some reason Cucumber is trying to create a formatter named 'progress>', so you probably just need to find and remove the extra angle bracket.

---

Edit: This wasn't the problem at all, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630844/cucumber-format-progress-doesnt-work/7660250#7660250)

Comment: There is no `>`, i've try in console "cucumber --format progress" and it doesn't work too.

Comment: could you add the `--backtrace` parameter, and post the output?

Comment: also could you post the full command-line that you're running?